# How to translate/localize PrivacyPolicy.strings

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I need to localize my PrivacyPolicy.plist from my Settings.bundle.

All my 'directories' for different language-country (.lproj) are there.

I added PrivacyPolicy.strings and tried to add, as a key, the string for my  and associate it to the same string. Something like:

"My string" = "My string";

I thought I already see it to work, but now it does no more

Am I at the right path or not at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looked like my PrivacyPolicy.strings was not properly created. Once fixed, everything worked.